# Remove everything related to PHP on Debian Server

Tags: debian, php

I tried to compile PHP5.4 by myself with ZTS support which worked fine, but it seems that whenever I install extension with apt-get like apt-get install php5-mysql, it does not get installed into the extension folder of the newly compiled PHP neither is it enabled in the php.ini. Also many .so files are missing (seems like the php.ini from the build is made for windows?).

However, I would like to remove everything related to PHP somehow so I can try again with a clean(er) system. Is there any easy way to do so?

I tried to copy the files from the source folder.

I tried this tutorial and replaced the Version with 5.4.37 : http://eddmann.com/posts/compiling-php-5-5-with-zts-and-pthreads-support/

Latest errors I had

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo.so: undefined symbol: executor_globals_id in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/curl.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/curl.so: undefined symbol: core_globals_id in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: enchant: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with build ID=API20100525,TS\nPHP    compiled with build ID=API20100525,NTS\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/gd.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/gd.so: undefined symbol: ts_resource_ex in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: gmp: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with build ID=API20100525,TS\nPHP    compiled with build ID=API20100525,NTS\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/imap.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/imap.so: undefined symbol: file_globals_id in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/interbase.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/interbase.so: undefined symbol: core_globals_id in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/intl.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/intl.so: undefined symbol: executor_globals_id in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/ldap.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/ldap.so: undefined symbol: executor_globals_id in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/mssql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/mssql.so: undefined symbol: executor_globals_id in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/odbc.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/odbc.so: undefined symbol: core_globals_id in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo_dblib.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo_dblib.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_unregister_driver in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo_firebird.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo_firebird.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_unregister_driver in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo_odbc.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo_odbc.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo_pgsql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo_pgsql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo_sqlite.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo_sqlite.so: undefined symbol: core_globals_id in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pspell: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with build ID=API20100525,TS\nPHP    compiled with build ID=API20100525,NTS\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: recode: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with build ID=API20100525,TS\nPHP    compiled with build ID=API20100525,NTS\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/snmp.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/snmp.so: undefined symbol: executor_globals_id in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/sqlite3.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/sqlite3.so: undefined symbol: core_globals_id in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/tidy.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/tidy.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/xmlrpc.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/xmlrpc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/xsl.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/xsl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Feb 18 14:26:15 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) PHP/5.4.36-0+deb7u3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Feb 18 14:26:19 2015] [error] [client 5.10.162.170] Couldn't locate driver named mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5
sudo apt-get purge php5
sudo apt-get clean
```

Hope this works for you.